# OpenSuse 12.1/Apache2 directory displays instead of index.html page

Tags: apache-http-server

Why does the index.html page (it works) not display, a directory listing page 
is displayed instead.  Setting are all the install defaults.  Index.html is located in
/svr/www/htdocs

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy paste your server configuration - in particular DOcumentRoot ? Also what is your DirectoryIndex set to ?

If you specify index.html to DirectoryIndex as noted below:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

then a request for http://someweb/ should return http://someweb/index.html if it exists, or would list the directory if it did not. So I guess it is related to something similar